# How to pass RequestContext to middleware using Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to register a middleware through a group of routes (Blueprint).

#### What I need

This middleware needs to **access to the incoming request data**.
I'd like to avoid using decorators if possible.

#### What I have

My Folder struct :

- app.py <-- entry point of application
- routes/

  - api.py <-- contains certains route related to api
- middleware/

  - authenticated <-- The middleware that needs to access request.json
  - other middlewares...

My routes/api.py

```py
import os

from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

# grouping routes under API
api_blueprint = Blueprint('dataframe_manipulation', os.getenv('APP_NAME'))


@api_blueprint.route('/health')
def health_status():  # put application's code here
    return jsonify({
        'status': 'ok'
    }), 200


@api_blueprint.route('/compute')
def compute():
    return 'hello'
```

In my app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    return Hello World

app.before_request_funcs = {
    'dataframe_manipulation': [authenticated]
}

app.register_blueprint(api.api_blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In my authenticated.py

```py
def authenticated:
    """Verification if user is authentificated"""
    # print(request) <-- Working outside of request context
```

**What I obtain**

RuntimeError: Working outside of request context

Thanks in advance,

Tanuki

Comment: What do you intend to do with this: app.before_request_funcs = {
    'dataframe_manipulation': [authenticated]
}

Comment: Hi,

I'd like to register multiple middlewares to the routes which are contained inside dataframe_manipulation.

app.before_request_funcs = { 'dataframe_manipulation': [middleware1, middleware2,...]}

If middleware 1 is ok then process the second, and so on until it reaches the selected route

Comment: But are you trying to run this before a view function is called?

Comment: Have you tried registering a blueprint earlier and initializing `app.before_request_funcs` later?